# Symfony 4: Doctrine-entity returns different data based on ROLE_*

Tags: php, symfony, security, symfony4

I got an `Account`-entity which should return different data based on roles of the currently logged in user:

```
return [                                     // to be returned if user has role:
    'id' => $this->id,                       // ROLE_USER, ROLE_PAYED, ROLE_ADMIN
    'name' => $this->name,                   // ROLE_USER, ROLE_PAYED, ROLE_ADMIN
    'hobbies' => ['some', 'tags'],           // ROLE_PAYED, ROLE_ADMIN
    'roles' => ['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_PAYED']   // ROLE_ADMIN
];
```

If I would make this change inside a Controller I would simply call a [voter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html). But I would like to use it inside the entity's [`jsonSerialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php)-function so that it's implemented inside every request without exception.

I'll guess the real question is "how to get a voter inside an entity", but I actually don't know enough about Symfony (using it only for 10 days now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voters are services and services really should not be inside of Entities. Entities should not have any knowledge about anything in the view or controller. If you find yourself needing services inside of Entities it is usually a sign that you need to rethink your architecture.

The approach I would take is to create a `JsonSerializeAccount` Service that uses the `AuthorizationChecker` to create the json array.

```
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationCheckerInterface;
use App\Entity\Account;

class JsonSerializeAccount {
    /**
     * @var AuthorizationCheckerInterface
     */
    private $authorizationChecker;

    public function __construct(AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authorizationChecker)
    {
        $this->authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize(Account $account): array
    {
        $json = [
            'id' => $account->getId(),
            'name' => $account->getName(),
        ];

        if ($this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('view_hobbies', $account)) {
            $json['hobbies'] = $account->getHobbies();
        }

        if ($this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('view_roles', $account)) {
            $json['roles'] = $account->getRoles();
        }

        return $json;
    }
}
```